# Is there an enterprise message queue which can drop duplicate messages (first value stays)?

Tags: jms, message-queue, messaging, duplicates

I am looking looking for a message queue with these requirements. Couldn't find it; maybe the closest was the rabbitmq-lvc plugin (but I need the first value in the line to stick and stay in front). 
Would anyone know a technology to support these?

- message queue is FIFO
- if a duplicate message is being enqueued, the message queue itself either rejects or drops it.

For example, producers put these three messages (each with a discriminator value) into the queue in this sequence: M1(discriminator=7654), M2(discriminator=2435), M3(discriminator=7654).
Now I want the message queue to see that M3 has the same discriminator value as M1 and thus drop/reject M3. Consumers receive only: M1, M2.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the other transports but I know that WebSphere MQ doesn't do this and I believe that the explanation why would apply broadly across the category.  I'd be very surprised to find that any messaging *transport* actually provides this.  Here are a few reasons why:

- Async messages are supposed to be atomic.  Different vendors make their own accommodations for message affinity (a relationship between two or more messages) but as a rule, message affinity is to be avoided.  Your use case not only requires the transport to deal with message affinity, but to do so over an indeterminate interval between related messages.
- Message payload is a blob.  For performance reasons, WMQ doesn't touch message payloads except for things like compression or code page conversion.  Anything that requires parsing the message payload is a job for WebSphere Message Broker, DataPower or WebSphere ESB.  I would expect any messaging transport which claims to be performant would face similar issues because parsing payloads results in longer code paths and non-linear performance degradation.  The exception is message properties but WMQ uses these for selection only and I expect that is generally the case.
- Stateless operation.  As a transport, the state of the application may be stored in a persistent message but the state of the transport layer should not depend on the state of the application *across different units of work*.  Again, an ESB type of product is best suited when you want to delegate *management* of some of the application state to the messaging layer and especially when such management spans many units of work.
- Assured delivery. WMQ was designed to never lose your persistent message.  If the app explicitly sets expiry the message might go away *because the sender said it was OK to do so*.  If the message is non-persistent it might go away, but only in an exceptional condition and, again, *because the sender said it was OK to do so*.  The use case you describe might result in a message going away not because the sender said it was OK, or even because the recipient said it was OK but because of an interaction with some unrelated 3rd party who happened to beat you to the queue with a duplicate value.  What if that first message has an invalid header or code page problem and gets rolled back?  What if I as an attacker spew out garbage messages with all possible 4-digit values for discriminator?

As I said, I don't know the other messaging products so there may be something out there which meets your requirement and if so I'll be interested to read about it.  However in the event hat nobody replies, this post may shed some light on the reasons why.

Comment: Thanks T Rob. I can see why not having a messaging queue inspect message bodies and why not to have it discard them is the right approach. I can work around this by using an external table which keeps track of processing (discriminator -> time of last processing). Then, whoever took a message of the queue, they can decide themselves if it is time to process or time to discard. Need to add a little overhead for the table queries; but maybe a better model.

Comment: Glad it was a helpful post, but I was kinda looking forward to alternative replies just so I could read about what the other transports do about this sort of requirement. In any case, thanks for the follow-up and accept.